# How to pass a input from a HTML <form> to a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, heatmap

I need to pass input (latitude & longitude) from a `<form></form>` to a Javascript function that will plug the point into a heatmap. I figured out how to gather the response and store it in a variable, but now I need to append it to a list in a different function in a certain format.

HTML Form:

```
<form name="sightings" action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="City, Town, etc.">
    <input type="submit" value="Sighting" onClick="formResults(this.form)">
</form>
```

Turning `<input>` into a  JS var:

```
function formResults (form) {
    var areaTyped = form.area.value;
    alert ("Your data has been submitted.");
    return areaTyped;
}
```

The list of points that I need to append the variable to:

```
function getPoints() {
    var heatmapData = [
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447), weight: 0.5},
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.437),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.443),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.439),
    ]
    return heatmapData;
}
```

Every point in the array `heatmapData` needs to be in the format new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude). Is it possible to take my each variable from the HTML form and append them to the list of points in the proper format.

The heatmap works and looks like this: [Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsAFg.png).

But the heated spot is only the points I gave it manually. How do I connect the input from my `<form>` to the heatmap?

Comment: submit buttons submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your search box into the map (see the [Places search box sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)), then when the user selects a suggestion from the google map search, add a point to the heatmap layer and call `heatmap.setData()` with the updated array of points. See example below:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

var heatmapData = [
    {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447), weight: 0.5},
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.437),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.443),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.439),
    ];
function initMap() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map-canvas");
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title: "Hello World!"
  });

  // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
  marker.setMap(map);
  var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: heatmapData,
          map: map
        });
  var input = document.getElementById('area');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  var markers = [];
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }

      heatmapData.push(place.geometry.location);
      heatmap.setData(heatmapData);

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    //map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

}
```

```css
#mapContainer,
#map-canvas {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places,visualization'></script>
<form name="sightings" action="" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="City, Town, etc." id="area" class="controls">
  <!-- not needed anymore: <input type="button" value="Sighting" onClick="searchMap()">-->
</form>
<div id="mapContainer">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```